# rails 3 controller select models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have something not working like i want in my controller.

my controller

```
  if params[:commit]
  @search = Building.select('buildings.id, buildings.slug, floors.id, spaces.id, buildings.name, floors.floor_number, spaces.space_number').joins('INNER JOIN floors ON floors.building_id = buildings.id INNER JOIN spaces ON spaces.floor_id = floors.id')
  @search = @search.where("buildings.name like '%#{params[:building_name]}%'") if !params[:building_name].blank?
  #@search = @search.where("buildings.name like ?", params[:building_name]) if !params[:building_name].blank?
  if params[:space_type].present?
    @search = @search.where("spaces.space_type_id = ?", params[:space_type][:space_type_id]) if !params[:space_type][:space_type_id].blank?
  end
  @search = @search.where("floors.min_net_rent >= #{params[:floor_min_rent]}") if !params[:floor_min_rent].blank?
  @search = @search.where("floors.max_net_rent <= #{params[:floor_max_rent]}") if !params[:floor_max_rent].blank?

  @building = @search
else
  @building = ''

end
```

my models

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :floors

end


class Floor < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :building
  has_many :space

end

class Space < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :floor
end
```

the debug <%= debug @building %> return me

```
[#<Building id: 9, name: "234234", slug: nil>] (as example)
```

But i want to get information about floors and spaces.

Someone have an idea how to resolv this?

thanks.

Comment: What happens if you debug/print `@building.floors` and `@building.spaces`? Does it work in `rails console`? Also a little confused why you keep assigning to the `@search` variable; can you only search for one criteria at a time or something, enforced on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use []

example

```
@orders = Order.select("orders.*, cities.name AS city_name, countries.name AS country_name, customers.account_id as customer_acc").
      joins("LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.id = orders.customer_id").
      joins("LEFT JOIN cities ON orders.city_id = cities.id").
      joins("LEFT JOIN countries ON cities.country_id = countries.id")
```

in view:

```
<tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
        <tr class="">
            <td><%= order[:country_name] %></td>
            <td><%= order[:city_name] %></td>
        <td><%= order.type_code %></td>
            <td><%= order[:customer_acc] %></td>
        <td><%= order.detail %></td>
        <td><%= order.number %></td>
            <td><%= order.expire_date %></td>
        <td><%= order.status %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: i don't understand. the select use a models?

Comment: yeap It uses model but select data with aliases from other tables

Comment: thanks but that doesn't works. if i use alias in the select i get a undefinied method and my debug give me only 3 elements from the building only.

Comment: debug wouldn't show them because thay are not instanse variables of object , but you can access them with []

Comment: hmm.. maybe im not enought experienced to do what you tell. but the result of Order.select, you don't put it in a @ ? you put it in a variable like : order = [] and order = Order.select?

Comment: updated working example, so as you can see data from other tables is retrived with [] operator

Answer (score 0):

when you use select(), [only attributes belonging to your model will be accessible through your record object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields). You then have to use associations like @building.floors, @floor.building... to process data. Have a close look at [the association methods that ActiveRecord creates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference).

I'd moreover recommend, as you're looking for information on floors and spaces, to start your query on Floor or Space, not on Building.

Comment: I've read your links, but i don't understand what you say. If i need all informations, i need to get the last to first? like Space.Floor.Building.select() ?

Comment: when you do something like Building.find(1), ActiveRecord creates a new instance of a Building object, which attributes are set to match the results of the underlying query. If your query returns some fields that ActiveRecord does not recognize as "normal" attributes of a Building object, it just ignores them.
AR automatically creates attribute accessors for each column on the table related to the model, and various methods to access to records from other tables related to a single record.

Comment: ...this means you cannot get all informations at once, stuffed in a unique object. if you have a list of buildings for instance, and you want to gather information on their floors, you have to use association methods like `@a_particular_building.floors.collect &:min_net_rent`. Sorry but i can't seem to make myself clear, i think the best for you is to make sure you really understand what's written on the Association guide.

Answer (score 0):

@neimad, not a direct answer to your question but you're leaving yourself open for [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by directly embedding your params in your query:

i.e.

```
@search = @search.where("buildings.name like '%#{params[:building_name]}%'") if !params[:building_name].blank?
```

is vulnerable if I set `params[:building_name]` to something malicious.

using

```
@search = @search.where("buildings.name like ?", "%#{params[:building_name]}%") if !params[:building_name].blank?
```

on the other hand, will properly escape your `build_name` param.

Even if I'm not being malicious, searching for building name: `Kristian's Building` will break this query.  Same problem applies to floor rent max/min conditions